# Finding polynomials from huge sets of points

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Let's say we have 1000 points, 
 \begin{align*} (a_1 &, b_1) \\ (a_2 &, b_2) \\ & \vdots \\ (a_{1000} &, b_{1000})  \\ \end{align*}
and we want to find a 999 degree polynomial that fits these points. The method I have in mind is to have a polynomial 
$$c_{999}x^{999}+c_{998}x^{99}+\ldots+c_1x+c_0=y$$
We would then plug in each of the 1000 points to get a huge matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1000}^{999} &  a_{1000}^{998} & \dots & a_{1000}^{0}\\
a_{999}^{999} &  a_{999}^{998}\\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots\\
a_1^{999} & \ldots & \ldots &a_1^0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
c_{999} \\
c_{998} \\
\vdots \\
c_0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{1000} \\
b_{999} \\
\vdots \\
b_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, this matrix is probably really hard to solve, because of the size of the numbers ($a_{1000}^{999}$ is huge), and the size of the matrix. I am doing this in Java, and I don't even know how to store numbers that big.

**Is there a better way of doing this than using matrices that is more efficient?**

Comment: are you interested in that from a theorical point of view ?(then the answers below are fairly good) or do you have a practical problem at hand ? and if so, why do you need such a high degree polynomial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of thinking about this is the [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial):

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{1000}b_i\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j \ne i}}^{1000} \frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j} .$$

I think if you're sufficiently clever you can write code for this that will be slightly more efficient than a standard matrix division but at $n=1000$ it might not even be worth it.

Of course, if you're using scipy to calculate these, [there's already a function for that](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html) and if you're using a different system like MATLAB you can likely use a ready-made function like that as well, which deals with edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This is a standard problem in numerical analysis, and two possible solutions include using [Lagrange interpolating polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), and [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) for interpolation.

Comment: Correct answer, but link only answers are discouraged on this site.

Comment: This is a fair response, but I felt it would be more useful for OP to have an introduction to the ideas to read more about this very broad topic than a short m.se reply.

Comment: Fair enough, and those are reliable links.